Update wordpress post meta after subscription cancelled with Gravity Forms
I have a subscription that controls a CPT item's premium status. I am using GravityForms along with its stripe gateway. I have this current code I've made:
add_action( 'gform_subscription_canceled', 'remove_premium_status', 10, 3 );
function remove_premium_status( $entry, $feed, $transaction_id ) { 
    $contractor_id = rgar( $entry, '9' );
    
    $payment_date = rgar( $entry, 'payment_date' );
    $downgrade_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 minutes', $payment_date));
    $current_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 
    if ( $contractor_id && $current_date_time > $downgrade_date) {
        update_post_meta( $contractor_id, 'premium-contractor', 'false', 'true');
    }
}

This works great without the AND condition as it cancels right away. Issue is, I want it to cancel at the end of the payment period. Right now I have it set to +5 minutes for testing. When I go to cancel and the "$current_date_time > $downgrade_date" is in place in the if statement, it never ends up canceling. The $payment_date variable is already in the same format as the other two dates. Is there something else I should add to get this to cancel the second the timer is up?
Tried to add the AND condition to check if the Current Time is greater than the Downgrade time set from the payment date. If both conditions are true, it should perform the action (which was tested alone and works). If the > gets reversed it works but cancels immediately which is not what we want.

The gform_subscription_canceled hook fires once, when the subscription gets cancelled by submitting the form. It doesn't magically fire again, at the time when the payment period actually ends.
